# Convert string to DateTimeOffset ignoring time zones

Tags: c#, timezone, datetimeoffset

I've created a `string` *extension method* which will convert the specific `string` to `DateTimeOffset`. I executed the following method:

```
public static DateTimeOffset? ConvertToDateTimeOffset(this string text)
{
    DateTimeOffset date;

    if (DateTimeOffset.TryParse(text, out date))
    {
        return date;
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

with this string:

```
"2010-05-10".ConvertToDateTimeOffset()
```

I want to get back the following result:

```
{2010. 05. 10. 0:00:00 +00:00}
```

But the actual result of my execution method call is (please, notice `+02:00`):

```
{2010. 05. 10. 0:00:00 +02:00}
```

How can I eliminate this *time zone issue*?

Comment: `if (DateTimeOffset.TryParse(text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal, out date)) {...}`

Answer (score 9):

If you want *UTC*, not *local time* you have to specify it manually with `DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal`:

```
... 
if (DateTimeOffset.TryParse(text, 
                            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                            DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal, 
                            out date)) {
  ...
}
...
```

You can simplify the implementation (C# 7.0+) with `out var`:

```
public static DateTimeOffset? ConvertToDateTimeOffset2(this string text) {
  return DateTimeOffset.TryParse(text, 
                                 CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                                 DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal, 
                                 out var date)
    ? date
    : (DateTimeOffset?) null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397029(v=vs.110).aspx).

I believe that you are looking for

```
   DateTimeOffset.TryParse(text, null, DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal, out date);
```

According to the documentation

`Indicates that, if the input parameter lacks an <Offset> element, the UTC offset (00:00) should be provided.`